# Problems implementing a container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I'm trying to follow the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) to implement a container view in my application. At the moment I'm just trying to get an initial first view to load but the label included in the first controller is not being shown. In the end, I hope to be able to control which view is shown in the container by using a segmented control.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My Storyboard**

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentController;

- (IBAction)SegmentedControlValueChange:(UISegmentedControl *)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "FirstController.h"
#import "SecondController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FirstController *firstController = [[FirstController alloc] init];
    [self displayContentController:firstController];
}

- (IBAction)SegmentedControlValueChange:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
}

- (void)displayContentController: (UIViewController *)content
{
    [self addChildViewController:content];

    content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];

    [self.view addSubview:content.view];

    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (CGRect)frameForContentController
{
    return self.contentController.bounds;
}

@end
```

Comment: I am trying to implement the UISegmentedControl portion.

Comment: The ViewController refers to the first one shown in the storyboard. You don't need the other one, you can delete it.

Comment: @KatedralPillon I have provided an answer on your question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24929501/273173

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `FirstController` is part of the storyboard, then you'll have to load it from the storyboard.

Try doing

`FirstController *firstController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. One last thing if you don't mind - from a design practice point of view, should there be segues between the View Controller and the First and Second controllers?

Comment: I wouldn't bother. You wouldn't be using those segues - which imo, would just make that more confusing.

Comment: the `yourIdentifier` is it Storyboard ID or is it Restoration ID?

Comment: It should be the `storyboardId`

Comment: @JohnGrant will you please help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914901/how-to-implement-segmentedcontrolvaluechange-to-control-container-view