# where to get identifier for instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Suppose I create all my views in the storyboard, [similar to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886770/problems-implementing-a-container-view). For the method

```
SomeController *myController = [self.storyboard 
  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
```

where do I get/set "yourIdentifier" in the storyboard? Under `Identity inspector > Identity` are two options: `Storyboard ID` and `Restoration ID`. But per the document for the method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` neither seems to be the answer.

Comment: It's Storyboard ID; Restoration ID is for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a StoryBoard ID.

You can give it in storyboard as in image shown.

[image: storyboard ID]

Then use this id as

```
SomeController *myController =  [self.storyboard 
  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
```